# error message when transfer TX

Tags: go-ethereum

I am trying to send TRX form leadger wallet to my exchange TRX wallet my balance was reduce and deduct but the transfer is not done. I have attached the error message[image] i got

Answer (score 0):

You set the Gas Limit too low so the tx failed and was reverted.
When interacting with smart contracts, like calling a transfer function to send ERC20 token like you just did set an appropriately high gas limit like 200000.